# API to get suggestions for articles in a specific category

Tags: api, mediawiki-api

For a Wikia website (or any sites that use the Mediawiki API like Wikipedia), does there exist an API for getting suggestions for articles in a specific category? For example, I've tried using this:

> http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&limit=10&format=json&search=ame

but I don't know how I can limit the search to a specific category, for example: `Category:American Civil War`

Comment: Are you interesteed in OpenSearch-style prefix search or in a more general search in category?

Answer (score 1):

`action=opensearch` can't do this, you'll have to use [`action=query&list=search`](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=search&format=json&srsearch=battle%20incategory%3a%22American%20Civil%20War%22&srlimit=10) with the [incategory: keyword](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help%3aSearching#Syntax) (experiment with it [in the sandbox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special%3aApiSandbox#action=query&list=search&format=json&srsearch=battle%20incategory%3a%22American%20Civil%20War%22&srlimit=10)). However, the problem with this solution is that it depends entirely on search engine used by target wiki: default MySQL-based search can't do this, MWSearch used by Wikipedia supports it, CirrusSearch that will replace it soon will have a [very similar query syntax](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help%3aCirrusSearch#Full_text_search). Not sure what Wikia's search supports though.